# Unable to login with root user on yocto build image for beagle bone black

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack

I am unable to login as root user on beagle bone black image build with yocto.
I am getting fallowing errors.

**beaglebone login: root
login: can't set groups: Operation not permitted
Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.5 beaglebone /dev/ttyO0**

Answer (score 0):

Please change the owner of all `rootfs` component in the SD card.
For example,

```
cd /media/<user>/rootfs
chown -R root:root *
```